# Automatically initializing mySQL structures (without mysql shell)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

My ISP does not give me access to mysql shell and therefore I'm forced in to a manual import of the initial tables structures.
I can only use : phpMyAdmin and FTP to the SQL Server
Any idea how I could automate this with a PHP script? Apart from the last resort which consists of writing all creation steps one by one in PHP.
Perhaps something like a sql dump interpreter issuing the sql commands does exist ?

Comment: phpMyAdmin has an 'Import' option.

Comment: you are not answering the question. Using phpMyAdmin import is a manual operation, I want to avoid this 'Import' manual step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you have to create your own interpreter.... quite simple simple actually.